# How to initialize/define child class with use class scope not class method scope?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-class

How to initialize child class with use class scope?
How to pass parent abstract class scope to child class?

I can write this code but with every call of getChild I will create one class but want avoid:

```
class Parent(object): # abstract class!
  @staticmethod
  def getParentName():
    raise NotImplementedError()

  @classmethod
  def getChild(cls): # solid class
    class Child(object):
      @staticmethod
      def getChildName():
        return 'Child of ' + cls.getParentName()
    return Child

class SomeParent(Parent):
  @staticmethod
  def getParentName():
    return 'Solid Parent'

print SomeParent.getChild().getChildName() # == 'Child of Solid Parent'
```

How to convert this code above into defining child class in parent scope (consider that parent is abstract so we cannot use Parent2.getParentName() since it will be overridden?

```
class Parent2(object): # abstract class!
  @staticmethod
  def getParentName()
    raise NotImplementedError()

  class Child2(object): # solid class
    # what code here to do the same like Child???
    pass

class SomeParent2(Parent): # final class
  @staticmethod
  def getParentName()
    return 'Solid Parent2'

SomeParent2.getChildClass().getChildName() # == 'Child of Solid Parent2'
```

Any help or hint will be welcome apart what is not constructive.

Comment: Not quite sure what your getting at, but look into [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html).

Comment: Search for "python nested classes" ... basically the `Child2` class does not know anything about the class that it is contained in. You will always have to inject that info in as you do with your `getChildClass()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot**.

Python does **not** have class *declarations*. It has class *definitions*. When you define the `Parent2` class, the indented code is **executed**. This means that any inner class defined there is created **before the parent exists**. Hence it is *impossible* to let `Child2` know about `Parent2` inside the class scope.
Note that this is very different from other languages, such as Ruby that *do* allow references to the class inside the definition.

Also note that your two examples do two very different things. If you put the class definition inside a method that a *new* class will be created every time you call the method, while doing so at the class scope means that only *one* class will be created
inside the parent scope.

Also I believe your design is broken. If `Child` is strictly related to `Parent` then you should either use inheritance, in which case you simply do `self.getParentName()`, without anything fancy, or you can use delegation.

If you really want to do that thing, then you *must* somehow "fix" the classes after the parent class was defined. In order to do this you can use a class decorator, or simply put the code explicitly after the parent class.

Comment: Design is not broken it is force by limitation. I can inherit Child from Parent but it not required! and also I can not inherit from Parent since it is abstract! I am not want to have Child per each Parent inherited class since Child always behave the same. Why I need Child and Parent - it because I need two handlers having same interface rendering different things from same data?

I can do pattern Data Viewer1 Viewer2 but in this case only Viewer1 is different so I do pattern class Data/Viewer1 + class Viewer2. It is stream html, css, js by three handlers joined together.

Comment: Think more about it I need class producing three handlers one for streming html, js, css to browser. From mess of widgets, css, js files inside html and css, js files inside and outside with some caching/conditional http. I am already almost done with some internationalization and localization. It simplifies code expanding with some perfomance sacrifice - whatever always is possible render static css, js from synamic or use memcache to simulate it.

Comment: Anyway I believe the solution would be a bit of a mess. If you inject the information inside the `Child` classes then these classes only know about *one* parent class. You loose the dynamism that `@classmethod` provides. If you provided some more examples code on how you want to use `Parent`/`Child` then maybe we could think of a better solution.

Comment: By design Child should read only top inherited Parent class and Parent class should harvest data required by Child - Child will ask Parent what js or css is need to be processed.

Child is final class it will never used for inheritance and can be used optionally as single copy only. It serves css or js build from mess of widget, css, js dependency.

As you explain it is impossible to use 2nd syntax since we need 'cls' at Child creation and it impossible to create Child after Parent without use @classmethod.